# URL Re-write causing 401 Unauthorized ASP.net WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api

Curious why when using a URL redirect my authentication fails on the server?

> Example:
> [www.url.com/users](http://www.url.com/users) -> works api.url.com/users -> works
> ww.url/redirect/users -> redirects to api.url/users -> fails
> authentication

Any thoughts on where this can we be adjusted?

Comment: hard to see in the example, but all of this is under the same url.com?

Comment: Sorry the formatting came out weird.  I have it working now via Postman, but I had to enable two settings:

1 - Automatically follow redirect
2 - Follow authorization header

#2 was the real issue, I need to to test if clients like iPhone and Android automatically do this or not

Comment: How do you use url rewrite? Can you show the rewrite rule and authentication code or confoguration?